# Why simple 2d game in unity lag?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a very very simple 2d game in Unity, but sometimes (every 2-3 seconds) there is a small lag. (on iMac, on iPhone, on iPad, on editor unity)

Information:

1. All textures reduced and still compressed (5kb - 100 kb) (aprox. 50 tex)
2. All scripts are optimized (In update I use only one Translate for one object which contains multiple objects(train with 10 railway carriage) with Rigidbody2D(isKinematic) and CapsuleCollision2D, 
   and small checkers (like if(sound != 1) then sound = 1))
3. Scene have about 20 objects (images, canvas, panels, 2 particles system (snow) with mobile shader > particles > additive and spawn one in every 1 second).
4. In Awake I set Screen.SetResolution((int)(Screen.width / 1.7f)), (int)(Screen.height / 1.7f)).
5. I have already optimized everything, and several times. He raised a lot FPS, reduced weight, increased smoothness, but small lags remained.

TODO: I created new clean project, I added 1 image and created script which translate image from right to left, and THERE ARE ALSO friezes!!!

When I play:

[image: When I play]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can there be some other app freezing your PC? Try setting priority for the Unity process at "High". That won't guarantee unfreezeing, but if it stops, there you go.

Comment: @AgentFire not work;(

Comment: Is it lagging only with the Profiler opened or in general? Note that the profiler adds a lot of overhead in gathering information especially if you have a lot of entries unfolded. From your `Statistics` it looks fine and says it runs with `116 fps` this should be more than enough for a human not noticing any lag at all ;) To see how the final app really behaves there is no way around building it and test it on the target device.

Comment: Can you click on the frame with the gigantic spike (in your first picture) and screenshot that?  It's mostly dark blue meaning your scripts are the thing holding up the CPU on that frame.

Comment: @derHugo in general

Comment: @Foggzie the gigantic spike is end of game, (it make screenshot for share),

Comment: Do you use lot of findgameoject and findcomponents and things like that in your script? if yes, then it might cause a lag. try replacing these with just straight gameobjects by dragging and dropping em in the script and then accessing them directly.